# Including a text document with an android app

Tags: java, android, resources, document

What is the best way to implement a text file into an android app?

I am creating an application that needs to use a text document as a resource - How do i include this so that when a user installs the app the doc is with it and the app has access to it?

Answer (score 5):

`assets/` (with access via `AssetManager`) or `res/raw/` (with access via `Resources`) are likely solutions for packaging the "text document".

Answer (score 1):

put it in your assets folder, and then access the text file through your assets folder

Answer (score 1):

There are two places that I would recommend putting your text file, either the `assets/` folder or the `res/raw/` folder.  Below is an example of accessing your file in each location.  For the below example, let's assume your file is named `example.txt`.

Assets folder:

```
AssetManager assets = getAssets();
InputStream in = assets.open("example.txt");
/* Use the input stream to read in your file here. */
```

Raw directory:

```
Resources res = getResources();
InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.example);
/* Use the input stream to read in your file here. */
```

Just a note, both of these assume you're opening the resource from a `Context` class such as an `Activity` or `Service`.